# Create standalone coldfusion file (cfml) that compares files and get missing labels

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfml

I´m working with [Preside](https://docs.preside.org/devguides/i18n.html), that has some `.properties` extension files used for labing and translating the web content.

In our app we can have several `xxx.properties` with others `xxx_yy.properties` where `xxx` is the name of the property and `yy` the language translation. The ones without `yy` are the default language.

Here an example for a default property file with his Spanish and French translations files and the **labels** `add_usser, edit_user, delete_user`:

**user.properties**

```
    add_user    = Add website user
    edit_user   = Edit website user
    delete_user = Delete website user
```

**user_sp.properties**

```
    add_user    = Agregar usuario web
    edit_user   = Editar usuario web
    delete_user = Eliminar usuario web
```

**user_fr.properties**

```
    add_user    = Ajouter un utilisateur du site Web
    edit_user   = Modifier l utilisateur du site Web
    delete_user = Supprimer l utilisateur du site Web
```

What I need to do is to create a standalone cfml file that retreives all `.properties` files on the application and compare each default .properties file with his other translation files and show the missing labels of the compared file, if they exist.

So far what I can do is to retreive all the property files in a query with the name and path with [directoryList](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DirectoryList.html) and print each one of them.

```
propertiesFiles = directoryList("/application/i18n/", true, "query", "*.properties", "Directory", "all");

<cfoutput query="propertiesFiles">
   #propertiesFiles.name &" "& propertiesFiles.Directory#
</cfoutput>
```

Can someone please tell me how to do the logic for looping and compare the labels of the default files with his translations using coldfusion? Or tell me an easy way to do it? Maybe embeding javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of all this is a label?

Comment: Sorry Dan, labels in the example I gave would be add_user, edit_user, delete_user. I updated the description with the information.

Comment: Though you can roll your own, there are already [existing java classes designed for that purpose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html).  Also, the file naming conventions are non-standard. i18n typically uses Locale language and country codes, like "es", rather than "sp". For example `somename_es.properties` (Spanish)  or `somename_es_ES.properties` (Spanish - Spain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop functions are one option.  The files in question look like a bunch of lines separated by cairraige returns.  Then, each line looks like a list separated by equal signs.

Also, there is an online library of user defined functions available for use.  It includes a function called [ListCompare](https://cflib.org/udf/listCompare), that can be applied to this situation.

The first step in my approach would be to write a function named `getLabels` that returns a list of labels from each file.  It would

1. read the file.
2. Create a variable named `labels` with a value of an empty string.
3. treat the resulting variable as a chr(10) delimited list.  Loop through this list and on each iteration, use `ListFirst(delimiter = "=") to get each label, and append that to the` labels` variable.
4. return the `labels` variable

The next step would be to use this function to get the labels from file `user.properties`.  Call this variable `AllLabels`.

Then start looping through the query created by your `directoryList` command.  Use the `getLabels` function to get the labels from each file and the `listCompare` function to identify the missing labels.

Answer (score 0):

Load each file into a struct so that all the name value pairs are known.

So for each file, loop through all the keys on one struct to see if they are missing from the second.

Also, consider loading all of this data into a DB. DB are better at handling sets of data.

Comment: That's an properties file  format & the  sentence are consider as string. We can't split it as structure key,vale pair. Because when ever you read the file all  lines are consider as single line sentence.

Comment: Read each line in, then use = as the list delimiter to get the key and phrase value, ie. Key=some phrase